# Nested list unexpected block positioning with set widths in CSS

Tags: html, css, list, position, nested-lists

I have nested lists that I am testing to make sense of a dropdown with slideouts that I am working on. Before the slideouts happen there will be "opening up" of nested lists that are shifted to identify how "deep" the user is. Oddly enough I have gotten my intended result, but don't understand why I can't use block display instead of inline-block display.

NOTE: The actual menu expands and needs to be dynamic for future changes, so MANUALLY SETTING the space for opening up is NOT an option. The list should be able to be added to/reduced without matching up new spacing.

The first picture is what I want, but I need to use inline-block on everything for the parent level list items to "open up" for the nested lists. I came to finally understand how it works by changing widths and realizing that any list items that don't have room to be placed inline auto line break down and expand their ul parent vertically. Is it just me or is this exactly what block display should do? I don't understand why when everything is block displayed that the nested lists no longer claim space in the parent list.

Sorry the CSS has a lot of unnecessary rules. I explicitly tree'd them out to help see what was where.

Thank you for any help!

With inline-block:
I get what I want, but I don't think it should be used. Don't trust with potential changing dynamics of the menu function.

```css
    body {
        padding: 50px;
    }
    
    ul, ul li, ul ul, ul label {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
    }
    ul {
        display: inline-block;
        position: relative;
        list-style: none;
        font: normal 16px/30px Helvetica;
        box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 0px 2px darkred;
        width: 100px;
    }
    ul li{
        display: inline-block;
        width: 100px;
        height: 30px;
        box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 0px 2px forestgreen;
    }
    ul ul {
        display: inline-block;
        position: relative;
        left: 50px;
        box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 0px 2px red;
    }
    ul ul li {
        display: inline-block;
        width: 100px;
        height: 30px;
        box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 0px 2px lime;
    }
    ul ul ul{
        display: inline-block;
        position: relative;
        left: 50px;
        box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 0px 2px red;
    }
    ul ul ul li {
        display: inline-block;
        width: 100px;
        height: 30px;
        box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 0px 2px yellow;
    }
    
    
    ul li:hover {
        background: #c3c3c3;
}
    ul.main label {
        display: inline-block;
        position: relative;
        left: 2px;
        top: 2px;
        width: 96px;
        height: 26px;
        box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 0px 2px darkblue;  
    }
    ul.main ul label {
        display: inline-block;
        position: relative;
        left: 2px;
        top: 2px;
        width: 96px;
        height: 26px;
        box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 0px 2px deepskyblue;
    }
    ul.main ul ul label {
        display: inline-block;
        position: relative;
        left: 2px;
        top: 2px;
        width: 96px;
        height: 26px;
        box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 0px 2px aqua;
    }
```

```html
<body>
<ul class="main">
    <li><label>&nbsp;main</label>
                                <ul>
                                    <li><label>&nbsp;second</label>
                                        <ul>
                                            <li><label>&nbsp;third</label></li>
                                            <li><label>&nbsp;third</label></li>
                                            <li><label>&nbsp;third</label></li>
                                        </ul>
                                    </li>
                                    <li><label>&nbsp;second</label></li>
                                    <li><label>&nbsp;second</label></li>
                                </ul>
    </li>
    <li><label>&nbsp;main</label></li>
    <li><label>&nbsp;main</label></li>
    <li><label>&nbsp;main</label></li>
    <li><label>&nbsp;main</label></li>
</ul>   
    </body>
```

With display block, which I think should be used

```css
    body {
        padding: 50px;
    }
    
    ul, ul li, ul ul, ul label {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
    }
    ul {
        display: inline-block;
        position: relative;
        list-style: none;
        font: normal 16px/30px Helvetica;
        box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 0px 2px darkred;
        width: 100px;
    }
    ul li{
        display: block;
        width: 100px;
        height: 30px;
        box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 0px 2px forestgreen;
    }
    ul ul {
        display: block;
        position: relative;
        left: 50px;
        box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 0px 2px red;
    }
    ul ul li {
        display: block;
        width: 100px;
        height: 30px;
        box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 0px 2px lime;
    }
    ul ul ul{
        display: block;
        position: relative;
        left: 50px;
        box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 0px 2px red;
    }
    ul ul ul li {
        display: block;
        width: 100px;
        height: 30px;
        box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 0px 2px yellow;
    }
    
    
    ul li:hover {
        background: #c3c3c3;
}
    ul.main label {
        display: inline-block;
        position: relative;
        left: 2px;
        top: 2px;
        width: 96px;
        height: 26px;
        box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 0px 2px darkblue;  
    }
    ul.main ul label {
        display: inline-block;
        position: relative;
        left: 2px;
        top: 2px;
        width: 96px;
        height: 26px;
        box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 0px 2px deepskyblue;
    }
    ul.main ul ul label {
        display: inline-block;
        position: relative;
        left: 2px;
        top: 2px;
        width: 96px;
        height: 26px;
        box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 0px 2px aqua;
    }
```

```html
<body>
<ul class="main">
    <li><label>&nbsp;main</label>
                                <ul>
                                    <li><label>&nbsp;second</label>
                                        <ul>
                                            <li><label>&nbsp;third</label></li>
                                            <li><label>&nbsp;third</label></li>
                                            <li><label>&nbsp;third</label></li>
                                        </ul>
                                    </li>
                                    <li><label>&nbsp;second</label></li>
                                    <li><label>&nbsp;second</label></li>
                                </ul>
    </li>
    <li><label>&nbsp;main</label></li>
    <li><label>&nbsp;main</label></li>
    <li><label>&nbsp;main</label></li>
    <li><label>&nbsp;main</label></li>
</ul>   
    </body>
```

[image: with inline block][image: with just block]

Answer (score 1):

I think all you need to do is don't specify the height of `li` elements. The problem with setting the height of a `main` `li` is that the next `main` will be placed directly below, but if you don't specify the height the element will expand to accommodate all it's child elements so it will look how you want because the label will still stay the same size

```css
body {
  padding: 50px;
}

ul, ul li, ul ul, ul label {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

ul {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  list-style: none;
  font: normal 16px/30px Helvetica;
  box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 0px 2px darkred;
  width: 100px;
}

ul li {
  display: block;
  width: 100px;
  /*  */
  box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 0px 2px forestgreen;
}

ul ul {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  left: 50px;
  box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 0px 2px red;
}

ul ul li {
  display: block;
  width: 100px;

  box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 0px 2px lime;
}

ul ul ul {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  left: 50px;
  box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 0px 2px red;
}

ul ul ul li {
  display: block;
  width: 100px;

  box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 0px 2px yellow;
}

ul li:hover {
  background: #c3c3c3;
}

ul.main label {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  left: 2px;
  top: 2px;
  width: 96px;
  height: 26px;
  box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 0px 2px darkblue;
}

ul.main ul label {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  left: 2px;
  top: 2px;
  width: 96px;
  height: 26px;
  box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 0px 2px deepskyblue;
}

ul.main ul ul label {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  left: 2px;
  top: 2px;
  width: 96px;
  height: 26px;
  box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 0px 2px aqua;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <ul class="main">
    <li><label>&nbsp;main</label>
      <ul>
        <li><label>&nbsp;second</label>
          <ul>
            <li><label>&nbsp;third</label></li>
            <li><label>&nbsp;third</label></li>
            <li><label>&nbsp;third</label></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li><label>&nbsp;second</label></li>
        <li><label>&nbsp;second</label></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li><label>&nbsp;main</label></li>
    <li><label>&nbsp;main</label></li>
    <li><label>&nbsp;main</label></li>
    <li><label>&nbsp;main</label></li>
  </ul>
</body>
```

Comment: So this looks great, but I realized there is a reason I didn't do this. If you do the mouseovers you will notice that it doesn't work how I intended. Maybe all I need to do is leave it this correct way, put a div to shrink the background hover size, and then nest the child list under that div? Not sure if that will work in the end, but I will mess with it and post if it works.

Comment: What is the proper etiquette where you have led me to the answer, but what you have posted now is not the answer? I want you to get the answer credit as the div thing I said about worked perfectly with your answer. This really saves my code on this since the inline-block forced line break was not allowing margins to get spacing correct and now everything works swimmingly.

Should I post the code, you add as an answer/edit or something and then I can give you the answer?

Comment: @Bushwhacker You could add your own answer and say `Thanks Rob` etc and also upvote my answer because it helped you. I'm not sure if there is an establisted etiquette, but I think what I said is probably the best way because you want to show the proper solution for anyone else who has your same problem.

Comment: no no no lol. Don't you get some better credit getting the answer?

Comment: @Bushwhacker But I think it's OK if you post your own answer and just upvote me because I didn't come up with the complete solution.

Answer (score 0):

@rob-kwasowski please post this as an answer so I can credit you. Thank you very very much!

```css
    body {
        padding: 50px
    }
    
    ul.main, ul.main li, ul.main ul, ul.main label {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
    }
    ul.main {
        display: inline-block;
        list-style: none;
        font: normal 16px/30px Helvetica;
        box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 0px 2px darkred;
        width: 100px;
    }
    ul.main ul {
        display: block;
        position: relative;
        left: 50px;
        width: 100px;
    }
    ul.main li {
        display: block;
        width: 100px;
        box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 0px 2px forestgreen;
    }
    ul.main div {
        display: inline-block;
        width: 100px;
        height: 30px;
    }

    
    
    ul.main div:hover, li.ended:hover {
        background: #c3c3c3;
}
    ul.main label {
        display: block;
        position: relative;
        width: 100px;
        height: 30px;
        box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 0px 2px darkblue;  
    }
```

```html
<body>
<ul class="main">
    <li><div><label>&nbsp;main</label>
                                <ul>
                                    <li><div><label>&nbsp;second</label>
                                        <ul>
                                            <li class="ended"><label>&nbsp;third</label></li>
                                            <li class="ended"><label>&nbsp;third</label></li>
                                            <li class="ended"><label>&nbsp;third</label></li>
                                        </ul>
                                        </div>
                                    </li>
                                    <li class="ended"><label>&nbsp;second</label></li>
                                    <li class="ended"><label>&nbsp;second</label></li>
                                </ul>
        </div>
    </li>
    <li class="ended"><label>&nbsp;main</label></li>
    <li class="ended"><label>&nbsp;main</label></li>
    <li class="ended"><label>&nbsp;main</label></li>
    <li class="ended"><label>&nbsp;main</label></li>
</ul>   
    </body>
```

Comment: No it's OK. I'm happy to just get an upvote. Good job fixing the rest of it yourself.

Comment: Cmon just do it lol. It wont even let me select my own answer for 2 days. I didn't explicitly say about the hovering... you did it.  Take your answer please :)